# Can't get responseText from ajax call XrayWrapper

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using the IUI framework and are trying to get the results from an ajax call.

As viewed in firebug, The call is returning an "XrayWrapper[Object XMLHttpRequest{}", however I am unable to extract the responseText from the object.

When expanded in Firebug, the responseText is listed as a attribute, however it is prefixed in a lighter gray text with get: "get ResponseText"

```
    var data = iui.ajax('login.php',{'userName':'sysadm','password':'sysadm'},'POST',null,xxxx(data))
    console.log(data.responseText);
```

I have tried many different methods including data.get.responseText, data.get('responseText') etc etc but are still unable to grab the response.

Any idea why ??

Comment: where is the callback ajax is async

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX calls are asynchronous which means it fires the AJAX request and immediately logs `data` to console. At this point, the AJAX calls hasn't completed yet. I'm not familiar with the framework you are using, but you need to use a callback function that executes only after the asynchronous request completes.

Reading the IUI docs [here](http://www.iui-js.org/documentation/latest/iui-documentation.html), it seems the fourth argument is the callback function. SO you need to do this:

```
iui.ajax('login.php',{
        'userName':'sysadm',
        'password':'sysadm'
    },'POST', function(data) {
        // callback function. Only executes after ajax request completes
        console.log(data);
    }   
);
```

PS - Also, you have an extra argument. The docs show only four arguments `url`, `params`, `method` and `callback`.

Comment: @arun killu - thanks, I am able to dump the entire object using just console.log(data), but I am only looking for the responseText attribute and not all of the other request variables.

Comment: If you only care about responseText, then only log that attribute: `console.log(data.responseText);`. It won't work the way you are doing it because `responseText` will only be populated in the callback.

Comment: Thanks, yes that did the trick, data.responseText works when called in the callback function, thanks so much :-)